# 'wrangle' mean in this sentence

Tags: word-meaning

My dictionary tells me that wrangle means **to dispute angrily**. But what does **wrangle** mean in this sentence? My guess is that Barry had raised lots of snakes before.

> Barry had **wrangled** snakes before, Roberta told the Tulsa World, which is why he was confident he would be able to remove the rattler from the road.

Comment: See : [Wrangler (profession)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrangler_(profession)).  The word "wrangle" is a [back-formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation) of "Wrangler".

Comment: @WendyG's answer points out the correct meaning of the word "wrangle" in American English.  I have never heard "wrangle" used to mean "to dispute angrily."

Comment: Did you read all the definitions or just the first one?

Comment: @Scott but every dictionary in their first definition says it means dispute angrily. Is it uncommon or regional? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you missed the second meaning

> 2- North American with object Round up, herd, or take charge of
>   (livestock)
>
> ‘the horses were wrangled early’
>   https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wrangle

Comment: I can imagine herd horses, but I can't think of herd/wrangle snakes.

Comment: Check out some movie credits. It wouldn't surprise me to see a ***[weevil] wrangler*** in the credits for [Master and Commander](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-aPp7Kiiyg), for example.

Comment: [Here's](https://youtu.be/MjDbacj5lGE?t=75) someone confidently and naturally asserting that director David Lynch is an ***ant wrangler***.

Comment: AmE writers often do this. Take a word usually used in another context and use it in a different one. As wrangle means to take charge of, it works great here.

Comment: @dan  You can't imagine rounding up or taking charge of snakes?  [It's pretty common in parts of the US.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rattlesnake_round-up)

Comment: Note also that *wrangling* is a *romantic* term that evokes iconic images of American cowboys with big hats and mustangs and lariats, leading hundreds of head of cattle across miles of empty plains, while *herding* is more mundane.  In other words, *wrangling* snakes sounds exciting, while *herding* snakes sounds tedious, and probably futile.

Comment: @dan if you think wrangling snakes is funny, you'll like this 10+-year old commercial: [Cat Herders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTwJzTsb2QQ). Note there is a subtle difference between *herding* animals and *wrangling* them, specifically the third definition in the above answer "to take charge of", or, in the case of the snakes, "capture alive".

Comment: In terms of animals, "wrangling" basically means "handling" for any purpose. Interestingly, in movie credits, the person who handles the puppets for the puppeteers is credited as a "puppet wrangler"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76976/discussion-between-user151841-and-barmar).